# Getting the select value to display in a new browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, return-value

Hey so basically this is my code, the first script running allows the selected value to be displayed in the URL.

```
 <!-- Adds selected value to current url extensions -->
<script>
  $(function() {
    var collectParams = function() {
      var params = { 
        Region:$("#search_region").val() 
      };

      if(params.Region) {
        location.hash=jQuery.param(params)
      }
    };

    $("#search_region").change(collectParams);
  });
</script>

<!-- Adds selected value to current url extensions -->

<select name="search_region" id="search_region" class="search_region">
  <option value="0">All Regions</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="135">135</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="136">136</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="137">137</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="139">139</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="138">138</option>
</select>
```

Below is the second script running. It's used to store the selection, it all works fine but is there any way to keep the selection stored once i copy the link along with stored selected value (**eg: www.example/dropdown-test.html#Region=137**)  to another browser or if anyone else uses it for it to have my previous selection stored and displayed on their side?

```
<!-- Stores selected value locally after page refresh -->
 <script>
$(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('search_region')) {
        $("#search_region option").eq(localStorage.getItem('search_region')).prop('selected', true);
    }

    $("#search_region").on('change', function() {
        localStorage.setItem('search_region', $('option:selected', this).index());
    });

});
 </script>
 <!-- Stores selected value locally after page refresh -->
```

I'm not sure if this makes sense but that's the best i can explain.
I also only need to be able to do this with javascript no php

Thanks in advance

Comment: When copying the link with a #key=val you can use something like 
`$(function() {
var hashParam = location.hash.substring(1).split('='); localStorage.setItem('search_region',hashParam[1]);
})` to initalize your state (Snippet is just a hint and does not check if hash param was provieded)

Comment: Hey I've tried this but the value continues to only store locally so no luck but thanks

Comment: I do not get this part: "is there any way to keep the selection stored once i copy the link along with stored selected value (eg: www.example/dropdown-test.html#Region=137) to another browser or if anyone else uses it for it to have my previous selection stored and displayed on their side?" -> What do you mean by stored and displayed on their side? Are we talking about different users on a different machine or what?

Comment: "different users on a different machine". so basically the id that's picked up in the link (www.example/dropdown-test.html#Region=**137**) should select the option that has the same id (`<option class="level-0" value="**137**">137</option>`) on another machine @Emocuc

Comment: OK, so am I missing something or you really have no backend (server side functions / db), but you want to share data between multiple users within one app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are about to share data between two clients directly, you will be facing numerous obstacles and since you just ask about the basic concept, I would not recommend you trying to code that directly, rather first study your options. If you want the data spread over larger pool of users, then you really should use some server side solution (lets say something like Firebase).

**PEERS**

Most likely you will go with some peer-to-peer setup. There are numerous technologies trying to target it, but all are somewhat tricky. Not all are well supported, some are buggy, others difficult to setup.

**TO STUDY RECOMMENDATIONS**

https://webrtc.org/

http://www.websocket.org/

**IMPLEMENTATION**

I suggest you first pick the technology you like. Then try to implement it and then you might like to post new questions regarding the specific issues, you will be facing then.

---

*If you go with P2P, I wish you best of luck. This sounds like from zero to hero story.*

Comment: Hey thanks @Emocuc. I'm not sure how far this will get me but in simpler terms I just want to be able to control the select options from the id within the URL, so if changed in the URL would it be possible to change the current option on the page itself?? Just a workaround thought

Comment: Since it is for different user on different machine, you need some networking. That means either P2P or server service. No telepathy so far in JavaScript, perhaps after JS runs on quantum processors with entanglement  :D

Comment: Well that was a fail haha...Thanks for the help and clarity on this though

Comment: @zuh - I am sorry my answer did not help you and I hope that I understood your question well and did not mislead you anyhow. But I encourage you to write server-side code or learning about P2P. I hope you will find the way to make your app doing what you want after all.

Comment: really, so how did you do that, you might answer your own question to give it some resolution ...

Answer (score 0):

Stores previous selected # value in URL and carries it over to another users PC when link is copied. If there's any simpler way of doing it, hola

```
<select name="search_region" id="search_region" class="search_region">
        <option value="0">All Regions</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="135">135</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="136">136</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="137">137</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="139">139</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="138">138</option>
    </select>


     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#search_region').change(function () {
            var url = $(this).val();
            window.location.hash = url;
            console.log('select Changed');
        });
    });
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

    window.onload = fn; // fire on pageload

    function fn() {
        $('#search_region').val(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
        console.log("hash = " + window.location.hash);
    }
     </script>
```