# How to Add two values from two selection boxes to one URL trail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

Here are both select boxes, what I need is if there are values selected from both boxes, both should be displayed in the URL, something like this e.g www.example.com#135+#140

```
 <select name="search_region" id="search_region" class="search_region">
        <option value="0">All Regions</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="135">HTML</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="136">PHP</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="137">CSS</option>
    </select>

    <select name="search_categories" id="search_categories" class="search_categories">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>   
        <option class="level-0" value="140">Java</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="141">Script</option>
    </select>
```

Below is this script I'm running to display the #search_regions value in the URL, so far it works perfect. Now to be able to add the #search_categories value to that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#search_region').change(function () {
        var url = $(this).val();
        window.location.hash = url;
        console.log('select Changed');
    });
});
window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

window.onload = fn; // fire on pageload

function fn() {
    $('#search_region').val(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
    console.log("hash = " + window.location.hash);
}
 </script>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

It's an add on from my previously asked question

[Getting the select value to display in a new browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457056/getting-the-select-value-to-display-in-a-new-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Build your url parameters in one step, then update the window location in another step.

That said, the location.hash is whatever param starts with a hash, I don't know how it will deal with more than one param with a hash.

Comment: An example of how to do this please, my javascript no good here

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to update the URL:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#search_region,#search_categories').change(function() {
    console.log(window.location.href + '#' + $('#search_region').val() + '#' + $('#search_categories').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="search_region" id="search_region" class="search_region">
        <option value="0">All Regions</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="135">HTML</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="136">PHP</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="137">CSS</option>
    </select>

<select name="search_categories" id="search_categories" class="search_categories">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>   
        <option class="level-0" value="140">Java</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="141">Script</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: For some reason this code doesn't work when I run it live. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Above code will give you result in console.. To update the url, you need to assign it to `window.location.href`