# Displaying two seperate select box values in a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, parameters

Here are both select boxes, what I need is if there are values selected from both boxes, both should be displayed in the URL, something like this
 e.g **www.example.com#135+#140** OR **www.example.com#135&140**
(It doesn't matter in which sequence as long as both gets displayed that's the main aim of this)

```
 <select name="search_region" id="search_region" class="search_region">
        <option value="0">All Regions</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="135">HTML</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="136">PHP</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="137">CSS</option>
    </select>

    <select name="search_categories" id="search_categories" class="search_categories">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>   
        <option class="level-0" value="140">Java</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="141">Script</option>
    </select>
```

Below is this script I'm running to display the #search_regions value in the URL, so far it works perfect. Now to be able to add the #search_categories value to that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#search_region').change(function () {
        var url = $(this).val();
        window.location.hash = url;
        console.log('select Changed');
    });
});
window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

window.onload = fn; // fire on pageload

function fn() {
    $('#search_region').val(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
    console.log("hash = " + window.location.hash);
}
 </script>
```

Any ideas on how to do this? it would be much appreciated

It's an add on from my previously asked question, find link below

[Getting the select value to display in a new browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457056/getting-the-select-value-to-display-in-a-new-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You need to apply change event of both select-box.

2.You need to add second select-box value to the `window.location.hash`also.

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(function(){
   var url = '';
    $('#search_region').change(function () {
        url = $(this).val();
        window.location.hash = url;
         console.log(window.location.hash);
    });
    $('#search_categories').change(function () {
       if(url !==''){
         window.location.hash = url+"&"+$(this).val();
       }
        console.log(window.location.hash);
    });
});

window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

window.onload = fn; // fire on pageload

function fn() {
    console.log("hash = " + window.location.hash);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="search_region" id="search_region" class="search_region">
        <option value="0">All Regions</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="135">HTML</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="136">PHP</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="137">CSS</option>
    </select>

    <select name="search_categories" id="search_categories" class="search_categories">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>   
        <option class="level-0" value="140">Java</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="141">Script</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: would an hashchange addEventListener still work with this??

Comment: @zuh  yes it will. I have added that

Comment: for some reason the values don't hold when copied to new browser window, shouldn't the id's be added along to the event listener?

Comment: @zuh  you can add that according to your requirement. Try that

Comment: all my attempts failed though, not sure how to do this properly

Comment: @zuh  please ask a new question for that. some-one will answer you for-sure. Don't forget to add your attempts (better if you can add HTML also)