# How do I pass two selected hash values through to a new URL while keeping both items selected in the drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, parameters

Everything works as it should. Just having trouble getting both select box values carried with the hash event listener. For now I only have `#search_region` in there and it carries over as it should. I need `#search_region` and `#search_categories` in there.

Output displays `www.example.com#135&140`. The link `www.example.com#135&140` as is should be able to be copied to a new tab and keep both values chosen selected basically.

Any ideas on how I should go about this one?

```
 <select name="search_region" id="search_region" class="search_region">
        <option value="0">All Regions</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="135">Camps Bay</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="136">Cape Town</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="137">Durbanville</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="139">Hermanus</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="138">Langebaan</option>
    </select>

    <select name="search_categories" id="search_categories" class="search_categories">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>   
        <option class="level-0" value="140">140</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="141">141</option>
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
// ADDS selected values to URL
$(function(){
   var url = '';
    $('#search_region').change(function () {
        url = $(this).val();
        window.location.hash = url;
         console.log(window.location.hash);
    });
    $('#search_categories').change(function () {
       if(url !==''){
         window.location.hash = url+"&"+$(this).val();
       }
        console.log(window.location.hash);
    });
});


// carries selected value over to new browser or new tab. *where the help is needed*
window.addEventListener('hashchange', fn, false);

window.onload = fn; // fire on pageload

function fn() {
    $('#search_region').val(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''));
    console.log("hash = " + window.location.hash);
}
 </script>
```

This is an add on from a previously asked question. Link below

[Displaying two seperate select box values in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577541/displaying-two-seperate-select-box-values-in-a-url)

Comment: Duplicate question asked by @zuh https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577541/displaying-two-seperate-select-box-values-in-a-url We can mark this as Duplicate or Close.

Comment: @AnupYadav clearly different questions regarding the same code. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just a matter of checking if there are two hashes and splitting it and setting the values to the select.

```
function fn() {
    var values = window.location.hash.replace('#', '').split('&')
    $('#search_region').val(values[0]);
    if (values.length > 1){
        $('#search_categories').val(values(1));
    }
    console.log("hash = " + window.location.hash);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code expects that the second element is only ever changed *after* the first one is. You should consider using the same event handler on both elements and constructing the right URL no matter which element receives the event. Remove the half-global variable `url`.

Secondly, in `fn`, you have to `.split()` the hash to separate the two values and assign them to their respective elements.

Comment: could you please assist with "constructing the right URL"? my JavaScript no good, asking is the furthest i got with this

Comment: Well, you had the right idea, since you already combined both values in the second event handler. You should do the same when the `change` event is fired on the first element, so the order of user interaction doesn't break anything.